# Can't set hazelcast ManagedContext when using Jet.bootstrappedInstance()

Tags: spring, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I want to run [`hazelcast-jet`](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/latest/hazelcast-jet) embedded in my spring application (ie cluster is in process / NOT remote). I also want my jet jobs to be able to access spring beans from the `ApplicationContext` (see [jet/spring docs](https://jet-start.sh/docs/api/spring)). I don't want to have to configure the classpath on each jet job, I want to use the JVM's bootstrap classpath.

I think I need to use [`Jet.bootstrappedInstance()`](https://jet-start.sh/javadoc/4.2/com/hazelcast/jet/Jet.html#bootstrappedInstance()) to get a [`JetInstance`](https://jet-start.sh/javadoc/4.2/com/hazelcast/jet/JetInstance.html) but this does NOT allow me to set the `ManagedContext` on the underlying [`HazelcastInstance`](https://jet-start.sh/javadoc/4.2/com/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance.html). The docs from `Jet.bootstrappedInstance()` detail the way in which I want to interact with Jet

> When you submit a job to a Jet instance that runs locally in your JVM, it will have all the dependency classes available

I've tried this:

```
@Bean
public ManagedContext managedContext() {
   return new SpringManagedContext();
}
@Bean
public JetInstance jet(ManagetContext managedContext, List<Pipeline> pipelines) {   ​
   JetInstance jet = Jet.bootstrappedInstance();
   jet.getHazelcastInstance().getConfig().setManagedContext(managedContext);
   ...
   return jet;
}
```

But I get the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported operation
    at com.hazelcast.internal.dynamicconfig.DynamicConfigurationAwareConfig.setManagedContext(DynamicConfigurationAwareConfig.java:981)
```

Please note that the normal way of calling setManagedContext(...) is like this

```
   JetConfig config = new JetConfig();
   config.configureHazelcast(hz -> hz.setManagedContext(managedContext));
   JetInstance jet = Jet.newJetInstance(config);
```

I can't find a way of combining `Jet.bootstrappedInstance()` with `Config.setManagedContext(ManagedContext)`

As a workaround, I've copied code from `JetBootstrap.createStandaloneInstance()` (a private method) and added `hzConfig.setManagedContext(managedContext)`

```
  JetConfig config = ConfigProvider.locateAndGetJetConfig();
  Config hzConfig = config.getHazelcastConfig();
  
  // turn off all discovery to make sure node doesn't join any existing cluster
  hzConfig.setProperty("hazelcast.wait.seconds.before.join", "0");
  hzConfig.getAdvancedNetworkConfig().setEnabled(false);
  hzConfig.setManagedContext(managedContext);
  
  JoinConfig join = hzConfig.getNetworkConfig().getJoin();
  join.getAutoDetectionConfig().setEnabled(false);
  join.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
  join.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(false);
  join.getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);
  join.getGcpConfig().setEnabled(false);
  join.getAzureConfig().setEnabled(false);
  join.getKubernetesConfig().setEnabled(false);
  join.getEurekaConfig().setEnabled(false);
  join.setDiscoveryConfig(new DiscoveryConfig());
  JetInstance jet = Jet.newJetInstance(config);
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to run hazelcast-jet embedded in my spring application (I don't want to submit jobs to a remote jet cluster)

In this case using `bootstrapInstance()` doesn't make sense. It was designed to work with the `bin/jet submit` command where it creates a client instance according to the `config/hazelcast-client.yaml` or standalone instance for testing from your IDE.

For using Jet embedded you can use the [annotation based configuration](https://jet-start.sh/docs/api/spring#annotation-based-configuration) or alternatively you can use [Hazelcast Jet Spring Boot Starter](https://jet-start.sh/docs/api/spring#spring-boot-integration).

Comment: I am using spring annotations to configure my beans (see code above). If I use the `JetInstance` logic from your link, each time I submit a job I have to make sure it has the correct classes (via `JobConfig.addClass(...)` or `JobConfig.addPackage(...)` etc). I want to use the `JetBootstrap.createStandaloneInstance()` logic (see my workaround) which means I don't need to configure the classpath of each job, instead the job has access to the bootstrap classpath

Comment: So do you submit the job from within the application or from outside?

Comment: I do everything inside, I'm basically trying to use jet in a similar way to `apache-camel` or `spring-integration`

Comment: If you submit the job from within the same JVM you don't need to add any classes or packages, they are simply on classpath.

Comment: Incorrect, I get ClassNotFoundExceptions

Comment: In that case could you please file a bug with a reproducer at https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues, or share the full reproducer here, that's also fine.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce which is strange... unfortunately I didn't commit when I got the exception. All seems to be working now. My attempt at a reproduction here https://gist.github.com/uklance/e8b88da8028a7e391da616769d5745b4